# Unable to Disconnect a powershell session connected to office365

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I want to disconnect from a remote powershell connected to office365 and connect back later.

Tried the `Disconnect-PSSession` command but it throws error.

```
$UserCredential = Get-Credential

$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://ps.compliance.protection.outlook.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $UserCredential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection

.
.
.
.

Disconnect-PSSession $Session
```

(It redirects to https://nam04b.ps.compliance.protection.outlook.com/powershell-liveid?PSVersion=4.0)

The output I am seeing is:

```
disconnect-pssession : Disconnect-PSSession operation failed for runspace Id = 613e8071-b691-4365-84dc-2d65c21ea2fa
for the following reason: The disconnection operation is not supported on the remote computer. To support
disconnecting, the remote computer must be running Windows PowerShell 3.0 or a later version of Windows PowerShell.
At line:1 char:15
+ get-pssession|disconnect-pssession
+               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: ([PSSession]Session1:PSSession) [Disconnect-PSSession], RuntimeExcepti
   on
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PSSessionDisconnectFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.DisconnectPSSessionCommand
```

Locally I have Powershell version 4 running. And `Get-PSSessionConfiguration` shows PSVersion 4 at server. Any help appreciated

Comment: Does `$Session | Remove-PSSession` work?

Answer (score 0):

As Theo pointed out, using **Remove-PSSession works** instead as it is **supported in versions of PowerShell lower than 3** whereas **Disconnect-PSSession was only introduced in PowerShell v3**. Hence your error message.

Please see this link to [Disconnect-PSSession](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/disconnect-pssession?view=powershell-6) where it stats:

> This cmdlet is introduced in Windows PowerShell 3.0.

Comment: I have Powershell version 4 running. And the remote computer here is the Office 365's powershell session. How do we check the version of it ? And `Invoke-Command  -Session $Session -Scriptblock {$PSVersionTable.psversion}` throws error.

Comment: `The syntax is not supported by this runspace. This can occur if the runspace is in no-language mode.
+ CategoryInfo          : ParserError: ($PSVersionTable.psversion:String) [], ParseException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ScriptsNotAllowed
+ PSComputerName        : nam04b.ps.compliance.protection.outlook.com`

Comment: Taken from: https://www.michev.info/Blog/Post/1687/using-variables-with-invoke-command-in-remote-powershell-sessions-in-exchange-online

As many of you probably know, Remote PowerShell sessions connected to Exchange Online run in the “no language” mode. Same applies to Skype for Business Online sessions, and in general is a pain in the royal behinds, as it prevents you from using variables, operators and everything else that can make your life easier.